# How to generate a 555 fixed time delay even if trigger button is held on?

Tags: timer, 555

[image]
Can any one help me how to make it when the switch is presed for long time but it will not affect the time delay

Comment: Why don't you try and explain what functionality you want (without mentioning the implementation) then, go on to say what new functionality you require with the button?

Comment: I want to make a auto off time delay circuit in which continuous input signal will not matter or affect the time delay

Comment: It's unclear what your *problem* is – what have you tried, where did you get stuck? Continuous signal – where, what?

Comment: If i press the switch for a long time,the time delay off this circuit is changing i want to prevent that changes in the time delay when the switch is pressed for a long time.Pls help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for an edge-triggered one-shot or monostable delay. The output should time out normally even if the button is held on.

[image]

*Figure 1. Edge-triggered on delay. Add components (1) and (2).*

Add components (1) and (2). A C value of 1 µF and R of 100 kΩ will allow it to rearm in 0.1 s.

**How it works**

- At rest both sides of C2 (the new capacitor) are charged to battery + by R1 and the new resistor.
- When SW1 is pressed the left side of C2 is pulled low and the capacitor action pulls the right side low too. This triggers the 555.
- Whether or not SW1 is held, the right side of C2 is pulled high by the new resistor allowing the timing cycle to begin.

Comment: Hi, What about the polarity of the C2 ?

Comment: What about it? Are you able to tell from the schematic which side will be more positive than the other?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this stuff (If it wasn't obvious from my question). If it was that clear I wouldn't have asked it. 1uF I have ATM has polarity marks so that's why I asked.

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question.

Comment: No, it's not a stupid question but you'll be able to work it out yourself. The only thing that can affect the voltage across the capacitor is SW1. (1) What will the voltage be on each side when the switch is not pressed (as shown in the schematic)? (2) What will it be when the switch is pressed? (3) Based on those two answers which side would you connect the capacitor '+'?

Comment: You are trying to explain that the plus side should be the one that goes to the pin 2 of the 555, right ? However, won't the both side get 9V when the SW1 is not pressed ? (It's not a parallel connection becasue of the C2, right ? ) That's why I'm confused. can we supply a positive voltage to the negative side of the polarized capacitor ?

Comment: Your getting it. "*Can we supply a positive voltage to the negative side of the polarized capacitor?*" Yes. As long as C+ ≥ C- everything is fine. Remember that the capacitor only cares about the voltage *difference* between its terminals. So when SW1 is open both sides are at 9 V with 0 V across the capacitor. When SW1 is pressed pin 2 will be +9 and the other side 0 V so there will be 9 V across the capacitor with pin 2 positive.

Comment: This circuit is problematic. When you release the button, the TRIG pin will almost always see a voltage higher than VDD. Maybe you can clamp it with a diode but I'm surprised that was never pointed out.